# How to search for multiple twitter ids in one request using twitter4j library

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

How to search for multiple twitter ids in one request using twitter4j library. Even using in clause in Search parameter would be helpful. Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by twitter id?

Comment: I mean the post id which is also referred to as since id in Status object of twitter4j.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please find some sample code below to fetch tweets based on tweet_ids.
Like other twitter API's, this API is also rate limited, in a single call you can fetch status only for 100 ids. Check the documentation for more details.
Also use latest version of twitter4j lib.

```
ConfigurationBuilder config = new ConfigurationBuilder();
config.setOAuthConsumerKey("consumerKey");
config.setOAuthConsumerSecret("consumerSecret");
config.setOAuthAccessToken("accessToken");
config.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("accessSecret");

Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(config.build()).getInstance();
long ids[] = new long [3];
ids[0] = 568363361278296064l;
ids[1] = 568378166512726017l;
ids[2] = 570544187394772992l;

ResponseList<Status> statuses = twitter.lookup(ids);

for (Status status : statuses) {
    System.out.println(status.getText());
}
```